# Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) Error

Tags: python, json

I am working with a JSON file (newbie) and want to flatten it in order to print out the data set to view

```
import json

with open('/Users/mitchellsullivan/Downloads/worldcup.teams.json') as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    print(d)
```

So far I have this and I get the error that says:

```
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I was hoping that someone could help point me in the right direction with this if possible

EDIT: The contents of the file look like this but each team has a different section, this is just one of them

```
{
  "name": "World Cup 2018",
  "teams": [
    {
      "name": "Egypt",
      "code": "EGY",
      "continent": "Africa",
      "assoc": {
        "key": "egy",
        "name": "Egyptian Football Association",
        "continental": {
          "name": "Confédération Africaine de Football (CAF)",
          "code": "CAF"
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: The file is empty or is otherwise not valid json.  Can you post the file contents?

Comment: just made the edit

Comment: maybe first read as `f.read()` and display it to see what you get. maybe it reads from different file.

Answer (score 0):

You asked one question about a form. I did make a Pen for you but you deleted it. Check it here! [Code Pen for Flexbox 2 inline Forms](https://codepen.io/junaidanjum/pen/VwrorXr)

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='form1'> First Form </div>
  <div class='form2'> Second Form </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, they closed my question. This code did not work, I'm new to this but do you have discord? I would love to hear more insight about this

Comment: Yes, sure! add me on discord as winter#6387